# Fixing Incorrect Overlay of Self-Made Raster and Shapefile

Tags: python, raster, geopandas, python-xarray, shapefile

I'm creating rasters of Rio Grande do Sul, Brazil for part of a project I'm working on. They are successfully produced and everything looks good except for when I plot one on the same axis as a shapefile of the same state. Both should overlap as the same size and relative shape but instead, the SHP plots small and upside down. I need to fix this since my next step is overlaying them to do zonal statistics.

Here is the code I used to clip the initial netcdf I took data from and then what I used to write out the raster from an xarray dataset in case there were any glaring mistakes in the initial creation.

```
# Assign bounding lat/lon around RGdS
min_lat, max_lat = -37.0, -23.0
min_lon, max_lon = -61.0, -46.0

# Open dataset, clip
ds = xarray.open_dataset("path")
ds_clipped = ds.sel(lat=slice(min_lat, max_lat), lon=slice(min_lon, max_lon))


# Later on, create a raster from an xarray dataset called GDD_arr
outpath = "path"
with rasterio.open(
    outpath,
    mode="w",
    driver="GTiff",
    height=GDD_arr.shape[1],
    width=GDD_arr.shape[2],
    count=1,
    dtype='float32',
    crs= CRS.from_epsg(4326),
    transform = from_origin(-60.875, -23.125, 0.25, 0.25),
    nodata = -9999) as new_dataset:
  new_dataset.write(GDD_arr[0], 1)
```

Here is also the code I use to plot the raster and SHP and what it looks like:

```
# opening the raster and shapefile
tiff = rasterio.open("GDD_Count_ssp245_2020_tobacco.tif")
shapefile = gpd.read_file("RGdS_AgData.shp")

# set up plot
f, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot DEM
rasterplot.show(np.flipud(tiff.read(1)), ax=ax)

# plot shapefiles
shapefile.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I tried transforming the longitude of the raster to be -180 to 180 rather than 0 to 360 but the outcome still looks like this, with a small SHP that has been flipped vertically. I'll include a picture below this of what it should actually look like and a zip of the raster and SHP if that's any help. If anyone has any idea why this is happening or what I can do to get them to line, I would really appreciate it!

[Link to Data Zipfile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u3J_qM2SuDM3ZvLc1MnlwjG4zb2_A63h/view?usp=sharing)[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following line:

```
# plot DEM
rasterplot.show(np.flipud(tiff.read(1)), ax=ax)
```

You are reading the tiff pixels to a numpy array and then simply plotting the values in the numpy array. This way the georeferencing information (transform) is lost, so the pixels are just plotted as cartesian data starting from the (0,0) origin and with pixel size 1.

Try using the [rasterio plotting functions](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/plotting.html#plotting), as they will use the georeferencing data correctly when plotting.

The sample script below:

- reads the raster file from the zip file, and writes it again using the transform from your code snippet above. Edit: flip the pixel data before it is written, as it seems to be upside down.
- reads the rewritten raster file + reads the shapefile
- plots the raster using rasterio + the shapefile using geopandas

This is the result, the sea is now at the bottom right where it belongs:

[image]

Sample script:

```
from pathlib import Path
import geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pyproj import CRS
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
from rasterio.transform import from_origin

dir = Path(r"C:\Temp\bla")
tobacco_in_path = dir / "GDD_Count_ssp245_2020_tobacco.tif"

# Read the file in the zip file
with rasterio.open(tobacco_in_path, mode="r", driver="GTiff") as input:
    GDD_arr = input.read(1)

# Write the tiff again, using transform from the code in the post
tiff_path = dir / "GDD_Count_ssp245_2020_tobacco2.tif"
with rasterio.open(
    tiff_path,
    mode="w",
    driver="GTiff",
    height=GDD_arr.shape[0],
    width=GDD_arr.shape[1],
    count=1,
    dtype="float32",
    crs=CRS.from_epsg(4326),
    transform=from_origin(-60.875, -23.125, 0.25, 0.25),
    nodata=-9999,
) as new_dataset:
    new_dataset.write(np.flipud(GDD_arr), 1)

# Open the raster and shapefile
tiff = rasterio.open(tiff_path)
shapefile = gpd.read_file(dir / "RGdS_AgData.shp")

# set up plot
f, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot DEM with rasterio, so transform is applied
show(tiff, ax=ax)

# plot shapefiles
shapefile.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="w", edgecolor="k")
plt.show()
```

Comment: This fixes the orientation & size issues but not the overlay, the two still plot on opposite ends – is there something in the creation that's causing the raster to not follow the WGS crs?

Comment: I had a look at your zip file and read your tif + wrote it again with the transform info from your script above. I'm not sure what to expect, but for me both files are at least on top of each other when written.

Comment: Yes, it plots so close but the raster should be flipped vertically, the way it plots is upside down (the purple is the ocean here). I've been using np.flipud() for plotting but since my next step is zonal_stats from rasterstats, the original raster must be upright – just a new problem, thanks for your help!

Comment: Added np.flipud() before writing the data to the new file...